# Choice field composed of several IntegerRangeField in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a model where one of the fields should be an Age field, but that instead of being a simple number (`IntegerField`), I needed to be a Choice of several available age ranges `(5-8, 8-12, 12-18, 18-99, 5-99)`. I'm looking at the documentation of Choices, but I'm not even sure I can use directly an `IntegerRangeField` in this, so I ended up with something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    FIRST_RANGE = IntegerRangeField(blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(5), MaxValueValidator(8)])
    SECOND_RANGE = IntegerRangeField(blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(8), MaxValueValidator(12)])
    THIRD_RANGE = IntegerRangeField(blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(12), MaxValueValidator(18)])
    FOURTH_RANGE = IntegerRangeField(blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    FIFTH_RANGE = IntegerRangeField(blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(99)])

    AGE_CHOICES = (
        (FIRST_RANGE, '5-8'),
        (SECOND_RANGE, '8-12'),
        (THIRD_RANGE, '12-18'),
        (FOURTH_RANGE, '18-99'),
        (FIFTH_RANGE, '5-99'),
    )

    age = models.IntegerRangeField(blank=True, choices=AGE_CHOICES)
```

Is this the correct approach for this? This looks a bit awkward to me, I'm considering just using Char instead, although I'd like to stick to a have a Range on this field at the end...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think FIRST_RANGE and so on should be model fields. I'm not sure what `IntegerRangeField` needs, but assuming a tuple works can't you use something like `AGE_CHOICES = (((5,8), ('5-8')),...)`?

Comment: I see, let me give it a try :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Range Fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields) in django:

> All of the range fields translate to [`psycopg2 Range objects`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-range) in python, but also accept tuples as input if no bounds information is necessary. The default is lower bound included, upper bound excluded.

It seems you can use `tuples` to create the choices.

```py
FIRST_RANGE = (5, 8) # here 5 is included and 8 is excluded
# and similarly create the other ranges and then use in AGE_CHOICES
```

Alternatively, you can create the `Range` objects.

```py
from psycopg2.extras import Range

FIRST_RANGE = Range(lower=5, upper=8, bounds='[)')
# bounds:  one of the literal strings (), [), (], [], representing whether the lower or upper bounds are included
```

Comment: Hello, but I do need bounds...you mean use Range instead of using IntegerRangeField? Not sure I'm following you here

Comment: What type of bounds do you need? I mean do you only need to define the min, max bound or also include and exclude pattern?

Comment: @AlejandroVK, take a look at my comment.

Comment: @AKS I meant upper_lower bounds, integer fields for each range

Comment: @ilse2005 Does using a tuple instead of an IntegerRangeField (or NumericRange) make the upper and lower bounds be inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: @AlejandroVK Have a look at the update answer about inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: @AlejandroVK, sorry don't know. But I assume it uses default

Comment: @AKS Thanks for extra info! Looks nice, I prefer the tuple approach :)

Comment: @AlejandroVK I believe that you did notice that tuple follows some default behavior for inclusion and exclusion. If you want custom behavior you should opt for `Range`.

Comment: @AKS yeah, understood, it is ok for me this default behaviour, I will change upper and lower bounds accordingly, thanks